# What is node-lru-cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching, express

what is [node LRU cache](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/)? Anyone can explain how to implement it? Lets say I have three layers, client-midlayer(handle calls)-backend(mongoDB), and the LRU cache should be implemented in the midlayer.

Would be nice is there is a simple example just showing how it works! Thanks in advance.

Comment: A LRU cache is simply a collection with a fixed maximum size, that uses some method of removing least-recently-used items when inserting data once that max size is reached.  I don't understand what that matters to the rest of your question though.  This is simply a container; it is not a cache service.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on how to use it within the source repository: https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/tree/master/test

I'm assuming you want the LRU to persist to MongoDB? If that's the case, you'll need to extend or rewrite the library, as it looks like a simple in-memory LRU cache module at first glance.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. My ask is to keep five latest data from my mongoDB in a container that lives in the midlayer, which LRU can do the job i guess? But I don't know if it's the best way to approach.

Comment: @nihulus You're going to have to either write your own or figure a way to extend this LRU library on a cache miss event, which i don't see that this LRU module supports.

Comment: @EhevuTov Where does node-lru-cache stores the data by default? Is it in application's main memory?

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to consider Redis' sorted set for this. If you have multiple frontend server instances, keeping a single LRU instance per server will lead to them getting out of sync. Redis's sorted sets are a natural fit for this problem and are extremely fast.

You can use a timestamp to keep them ordered by most recent, and the list can be read and updated atomically via transactions. It will definitely suit the purpose of a cache well.

Comment: That's the solution I had at first :) I was thinking about something more complex.

Comment: @nihulus take a look at https://github.com/mcollina/redis-command-cache. It's a module that combines lru-cache and redis. You can send cache invalidation messages via redis pubsub.